# $\lim_{a\to1}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{a^{m}}{m^2}=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\lim_{a\to1}\frac{a^{m}}{m^{2}}?$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence

I am not sure if this can be done. I am at the end of a proof, an I would like to know if this is legal before continuing it. I would appreciate any advice!

Comment: In general, I do not think you can do this.

Comment: This might be what you are looking for https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_convergence_theorem

Comment: The question should be $\lim_{a\to1^-}\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\frac{a^{m}}{m^2}=\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}\lim_{a\to1^-}\frac{a^{m}}{m^{2}}?$

Answer (score 2):

First of all, I hope I didn't misunderstand the problem.

We prove the left limit doesn't exist. If not, assume $\lim_{a\to 1} \sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac {a^m}{m^2}=K$. Then, by definition, there is $\epsilon \gt0$ such that for any $a$ satisfying $|a-1|\le \epsilon$ we have $|\sum_{m=2}^\infty\frac {a^m}{m^2}|\le K+1$. Now, take $a=1+\frac{\epsilon}{2}$. Definitely, there is some $m_0$ such that:
$$(1+\frac{\epsilon}{2})^{m_0}\gt (K+1)m_0^2,$$
which is a contradiction.

On the other hand, for every $m$, $\lim_{a\to 1} \frac {a^m}{m^2}=\frac {1}{m^2}$; hence the right side exists and is equal to $\frac{\pi^2}{6}-1$.

Comment: Note that for $a>1$ we simply have $\sum_{m=2}^{\infty}a^m/m^2=+\infty$ since $a^m/m^2$ goes to $+\infty$ as $m\to\infty$.

Answer (score 1):

$\displaystyle \sum\frac{a^m}{m^2}$ is a power series which radius of convergence is $1$. As it converges for $a=1$, [Abel's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abel%27s_theorem) gives your equality. Of course one has to take the limit on $a<1$ ($a\rightarrow 1^{-}$) otherwise the left member is $\infty$.